# Is it a bad practice to have Context in MVP Model's constructor parameter?

Tags: android, android-context, android-mvp

I am trying to check internet connection using MVP pattern. For that I have a class `MyAppUtil` which takes `Context` in its constructor. This is my MVP model class where I am checking internet connection using `MyAppUtil.checkConnection(context)`  :

```
public class MainActivityInterectorImpl implements MainActivityContract.IInterector{

Context context;

MainActivityInterectorImpl(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void getData(OnFinishedListener onFinishedListener) {
    boolean result =  MyAppUtil.checkConnection(context);
    if (result == true) {
        onFinishedListener.onSuccess();
    } else {
        onFinishedListener.onFailure();
    }
}
}
```

Inside VIEW, I'm initializing presenter in the following way :

```
presenter = new MainActivityPresenterImpl(this, new MainActivityInterectorImpl(this));
```

As you can see, I am using `Context` inside MVP Model. Is this okay in MVP pattern? Any better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is bad practice. Make a wrapper of connection checker or similar thing and then pass it to model or presenter.

it should look something like this :

```
class ConnectionChecker(private val context: Context) {
val isOnline: Boolean
    get() {
        return try {
            val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(
                    Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo != null &&
                    connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo.isConnected
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            false
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

An **Interactor** can fetch data from your database, web services, or any other data source. After getting the data, the interactor will send the data to the presenter. Thus, making changes in your UI. You also can put the interactor in your **Presenter**.

Context is part of the Android **View Layer** in MVP, so the **Presenter** should not have any idea about this, and you should not transfer it to the **Presenter** or **Interactor**.

You must add needed methods to the **View** interface and implement it in your Android **View** components (for example, Activity or Fragment).